# Submit the dijit editor contents

Tags: jsp, form-submit, dojo, rich-text-editor

I am trying to learn the dijit editor. I want to replace an existing text area with dijit editor widget.So I wrote 2 jsps - one using the dijit.Editor which feeds another jsp with the editor contents.
When I click **submit** the second jsp *"result*" comes up empty contents for the editor no matter what is typed in text area editor.

**dijitEditor.jsp**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.Editor");
    dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.LinkDialog");
    dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.AlwaysShowToolbar");
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        alert("addOnLoad function");  
        dojo.connect(dojo.byId('form1'), 'onsubmit', function(){
            dojo.byId('editorContent').value= dijit.byId('content').getValue();
            alert("Hidden variable");
            alert(dojo.byId('editorContent').value);
            alert("Editor content");
            alert(dijit.byId('content').getValue());
         });
      });

</script>                   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
</head>

  <body class=" claro ">
  <FORM id="form1" METHOD=POST ACTION="result.jsp">

  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="editorContent" />
            <div dojoType="dijit.Editor" id="content" onChange="console.log('editor1 onChange handler: ' + arguments[0])"
                plugins="['foreColor','|','bold','italic','underline','|','createLink', 'unlink']"
                extraPlugins="['dijit._editor.plugins.AlwaysShowToolbar']">
                    <p>
                        <b>This instance is created with a subset of functions enabled in the order
                        we want. </b>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action"/>
             </td>  
        </tr>
    </table>        
   </form>    
  </body>
</html>
```

**result.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Editor contents </title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String val = request.getParameter("editorContent");    
            out.println("Dijit editor contents ="+val);  
         %>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of binding it to the form's `onsubmit`, try doing it via the widget's `onChange`

Give your hidden field an id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="editorContent" id='editorContent' />
```

Try this for the Editor's `onChange` (replacing the `console.log()` code you have there now.

```
onChange="dojo.byId('editorContent').value = this.getValue();"
```

---

**Wait!** As I was typing this I realized you are calling `dojo.byId('editorContent')` in your `onsubmit` but you have not assigned the `id` attribute to that form field. That's probably your issue and you needn't try my `onChange` method.