# dojo validation of dijit/Editor

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dojo, editor

I tried extending the post detailing how to mixin validation for a dijit/form/TextArea: [Dojo validation of a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072173/dojo-validation-of-a-textarea/16082704#16082704), to a dijit/Editor.

In particular to get the Editor to indicate it's requiredness upon the Form's submit.

Being aware of the Editor's content not being submitted as part the form I set the value of the Editor's contents, to be copied into a hidden textarea upon the Editor's onChange event: [Submit the dijit editor contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695581/submit-the-dijit-editor-contents)

However, **doom**, when I use the code below, the Editor displays the validation message upon the Form's submission whether or not there's text in it or not.

I also noted with firebug, that if I use the out of the box Dijit/Editor, the textarea's value is set on the onChange event - but the hidden textarea's value is NOT set when using the mixed in widget below.

```
    define("my_dijit/ValidationEditor",
        [ "dojo", "dijit", "dijit/_Widget",  "dijit/form/_FormWidget", "dijit/form /ValidationTextBox", "dijit/Editor"  ], function(dojo, dijit, _Widget, _FormWidget, ValidationTextBox, Editor) {
    return dojo.declare("my_dijit.ValidationEditor", [ dijit._Widget, _FormWidget, dijit.form.ValidationTextBox, dijit.Editor ], {

        invalidMessage: "This field is required",
        missingMessage: "A value is required",
        //regExp: "(.|\\s)*",

        // regExp: "(.|[\r\n])*",
        regExp: "(.|[\r\n|\r|\n])*",

        // postCreate() is called after buildRendering().  This is useful to override when 
        // you need to access and/or manipulate DOM nodes included with your widget.
        // DOM nodes and widgets with the dojoAttachPoint attribute specified can now be directly
        // accessed as fields on "this". 
        // Common operations for postCreate
        // 1) Access and manipulate DOM nodes created in buildRendering()
        // 2) Add new DOM nodes or widgets 

        postCreate : function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);

        },

        validate: function() {
            if (arguments.length==0) {
                return this.validate(false);
            }
                return this.inherited(arguments);
            },

            onFocus: function() {
                if (!this.isValid()) {
                    this.displayMessage(this.getErrorMessage());
                }
            },

            onBlur: function() {
                if (!this.isValid()) {
                  this.displayMessage(this.getErrorMessage());
                }
            }

    });
});
```

Many thanks for any consideration